# How to split a column into multiple columns using SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a column that has both the name of the column and the value for that column in the following format:

```
column_name
name1: value1 name2: valu2 name3: value3 name4: value4 name5: value5
```

Instead of having the setting above I want to have the columns in the following format:

| name1 | name2 | name3 | name4 | name5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| value1 | value2 | value3 | value4 | value5 |

The issue is that those values are not consistent through the entire column, sometimes I will have a combination of those values, sometimes none, and sometimes just one, but it doesn't matter how the order is, all those columns will have to be created.  how can call them in a generic way that I don't have to specify the values like this:

```
CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ',column_name)>0 
         then SUBSTRING(column_name,1,CHARINDEX(' ',column_name)-1) 
         else column_name end name1, 
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ',column_name) > 0 
         THEN SUBSTRING(column_name,CHARINDEX(' ',column_name)+1,len(column_name))  
         ELSE NULL END as name2
```

Comment: SQL Server <> PostgreSQL. Please [edit] your question to retag the RDBMS you are really using.

Answer (score 0):

In a situation like this I had to create a column type JSON as shown below [See the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bg9mF.png)

then you can store it this key value as JSON array and decode them when you want to use this data again.

**The downside** is that you cannot do search inside this array straight from database.

**Update:**  how to use JSON on redshift
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/json-functions.html

Comment: I'm doing this on Redshift, I'm not sure if that solution will help, but thank you.

Comment: @WendyVelasquez, there is an announcement that they support native JSON on redshift [here](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/about-aws/whats-new/2020/12/amazon-redshift-announces-support-native-json-semi-structured-data-processing/)

Comment: Thank you for the info, it will be helpful once I figure it out.  @Abdelraouf Ferah.  The issue here is, the table is already ingested on Redshift, so it is just one column that I will need to modify, not sure how to add that piece.

Comment: you welcome, you need to alter the column to type SUPER and change the query that is already ingested there is a good example of using column type SUPER https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_SUPER_sample_dataset.html